# Pointing man pages to different location

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, man

In my environment, I am installing a different vendor SSH server other than openSSH tended to meet our environment needs. When I issue a man ssh command, for example, I want it to point to the new vendor ssh server man page, rather than the openssh man page. The only way I have seen to do it so far is to physically copy all the man pages from the new ssh server to the /usr/local/man directory. Does anyone know of an easier/cleaner way to do this, such as a configuration file to point man to look the new man entries where I would provide a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control what `man` looks for using the environment variable `MANPATH`. Works the same way the `PATH` variable works. Directories are separated by colons, i.e. `":"`. Just prepend directories to the beginning of it to override where `man` looks for man pages.

in a bash shell:

```
% export MANPATH=/some/new/dir:$MANPATH
```

You can see what it's set to with this command:

```
% echo $MANPATH
```

Don't be surprised if it's empty. `man` makes use of a config file, `/etc/man.config` which drives where `man` should look for man pages. It will have entries like this:

```
MANPATH /usr/man
MANPATH /usr/share/man
MANPATH /usr/local/man
MANPATH /usr/local/share/man
```

You can see the effect of these entries along with your `MANPATH` variable with the command `manpath`.

```
% echo $MANPATH

% manpath
/usr/kerberos/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/en:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man
```